# JavaFX: Setting Drag Done

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, javafx-8

Currently I am developing a program which transfers a list item into another list. It works well with `setOnDragExited`,if I drag it to another component with the `setOnDragExited`, it will be dropped. (Which I think the program is rightbecause that is the function of setOnDragExited. But I need the program to only drop the list item when I release the button).

So I have the source which is `fieldList` and the target which is `mainTable`

Here is the code for the source, which I have no problem with.

```
fieldList.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
         public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                /* drag was detected, start a drag-and-drop gesture*/
                /* allow any transfer mode */
                Dragboard db =fieldList.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
                /* Put a string on a dragboard */
                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putString(fieldList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                db.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
         }
    });
```

And here is the code which doesn't work with `setOnDragDropped` but works with `setOnDragExited`

```
mainTable.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
             public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                 /* data dropped */
                    System.out.println("onDragDropped");
                    /* if there is a string data on dragboard, read it and use it */
                    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                    boolean success = false;
                    if (db.hasString()) {
                        ObservableList<String> ls = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 

                        try {
                            columnLS.add(Resources.getgBCon().getActualName(tableList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())+"."+db.getString());
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        success = true;
                        String base= "";
                       if(!columnLS.isEmpty()){
                            for(int i = 0; i<= columnLS.size()-1 ;i++){
                                if(i == 0){
                                    base = columnLS.get(i);
                                }else{
                                    base = base + ", " + columnLS.get(i);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        columnQuery = base;
                        me.refreshSQLQuery(columnQuery,getTableQuery(),filterQuery,groupQuery,sortQuery);
                    }
                    /* let the source know whether the string was successfully 
                     * transferred and used */
                    event.setDropCompleted(true);

                    event.consume();
             }
        });
```

So far I didn't find anything that relates to my problem, on those that are remotely related I found, I have tried but to no avail.
Thank you Stack Overflow.

I have added `setOnDragEntered`. It seems it still didn't work. Is there a difference between `setOnDrag` and `setOnMouseDrag`?

```
mainTable.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
             public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                     System.out.println("onDragEntered");
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
             }
        });
```

I have also tried TransferMode.ANY but to no avail.

Solution:
Used  `mainTable.setOnDragOver` instead of `mainTable.setOnDragEntered`

Comment: Did you enable the drop by calling `DragEvent.acceptTransferModes(...)` at any point? Typically you do this in a `setOnMouseDragEntered(...)` or `setOnMouseDragOver(...)` handler on the drop target.

Comment: I have solved it by using `setOnDragOver(...)` instead of the other one.

Comment: @DarkThunder: rather than editing your _question_ to include the answer, you should post the solution as an answer (it's fine to answer your own question on StackOverflow). This way, others will benefit.